# How to speed up reading Blu-ray images?

Tags: macos, mount

I have unencrypted .iso images of both DVD and BD (don't know how to check the UDF version used). When mounting and copying files off them, BD is around four times slower. Why? How do I speed it up?

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I solved this problem by using a specialized tool like makemkv.

Comment: @JoyJin I'd say you worked around the problem, in a way that only applies to video data.

Comment: I'm not sure MKV can store BD menus. I'm pretty sure it can't store a disk that isn't a movie.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that you can put anything you want on a blu-ray. I only have images of video blu-ray. Have you tried doing this on a linux system to see if it's due to macOS's implementation?

Comment: Yes, it was macOS. Have to try with current versions again.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution to reach Blu-ray or DVD ISO on Mac is to digitize ISO image to readable file type for iMac, this is my suggestion.